# passing text variable from text file to html form cell using php

Tags: php, html, c

The end goal is really simple. I need to red a line of text from a text file, parse it into a few variables and then display the variables within cells on a table within a web page. I have done this dozens of times using mysql but never a test file. The problem is I get a blank enry within the cells. However if I run from the command line, the data shows within the cells as it should.

In my troubleshooting I have taken things down to a bare minimum - just one variable and one cell. If I hard code the variable $mytest="15"; It works fine. If I grab the variable from the text file reading it into $mytest, it shows blank in the cell and yet from the command line it looks fine. I have even gone so far as set a variable to 15 and sent it to a short C program via exec and then set my $mytest equal to the return value and still blank.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/home/vm725d/vmbrr.v2.6.6.vticketQ.log", "r");
$line = fgets($handle);
        // process the line read.
        $fields = explode("|",$line);
        // Get data from fields
        $vticket = explode (":", $fields[0]);
        //$vTicket=$vticket[1];
        $vTicket="15";
        $mytest=exec ('/opt/observium/html/custom/fixstring ' . $vTicket);
        //$mytest=$vTicket;
        print "$mytest";
    fclose($handle);
?>
<html>
<body>
<CENTER><B>V-Ticket Test</b> </CENTER>

<TABLE>
<FORM METHOD="POST" name=modticket action=modticket.php>
<center><TABLE bgcolor="#258e8e" width=800 border=1>
<TR></TR<TR></TR>

<TR>
        <TD bgcolor="#FFFF99">vTicket:</TD>

         <TD width=24><input name="thing1" value="<?php print $mytest;?>"></TD>

</TR>
</table>
<input type=submit name=create_case value="Update">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fixstring C Code - remeber I am using this just as a test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[300])
{
        int length = 0;

        length = strlen(argv[1]);
        char NEW[length];
        memset (NEW,0,length );
        strcpy(NEW, argv[1]);

        printf ("%s",NEW);
}
```

when I set my variable $mytest to "15" The cell on my webpage show 15 for vTicket.

When I set my variable to the value in the text file or the return value from the fixstring C program it shows blank.

However, here is what I see when I run the php from the command line in this instance

[root@obs-stl-01 custom]# php vtest1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<CENTER><B>V-Ticket Test</b> </CENTER>

<TABLE>
<FORM METHOD="POST" name=modticket action=modticket.php>
<center><TABLE bgcolor="#258e8e" width=800 border=1>
<TR></TR<TR></TR>

<TR>
        <TD bgcolor="#FFFF99">vTicket:</TD>

         <TD width=24><input name="thing1" value="15"></TD>

</TR>
</table>
<input type=submit name=create_case value="Update">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet the page shows a blank field for the cell thing1

I can actually capture this output and write it to test.html and then point my browser to it and it displays correctly.

I know I am missing something really dumb but I am snake bit on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post a sample input file?  i.e., a 3-line `vmbrr.v2.6.6.vticketQ.log` file?

Comment: What's in the web server error log?

Comment: EXAMPLE input file below - single line. I started with all the fields in my script but quickly reduced it down to one variable since they all have the same issue.

Comment: vticket: 15 | From: John Doe | To: Jane Doe | Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 16:11:29 +0000 | User: Phil Collins | Program: TruthorDare | Issue: Cannot read text into v
ariable | Area: 51 | POC: C. Darwin |  Chargeline: R&D | ECD: 02/15/19 | Status:
 0%

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! This sounds like it might be a permissions issue to me. PHP is run from your user when run from the command line, but it is typically run by a different user by a web server, such as `www-data`. If your user has rights to execute the file, but the web server user does not, that would cause the issue you are seeing: works correctly run manually but not over HTTP.

To quickly check if this is your issue, try running `chmod +x /opt/observium/html/custom/fixstring`. Does it work in browser now?

Hopefully it does. However, this is technically an insecure solution, as now any user can execute the file. If you wish to be more secure, you should instead run `chmod o-x /opt/observium/html/custom/fixstring` to revert this change, and run `chown www-data /opt/observium/html/custom/fixstring` to change the ownership of the file to the web server, assuming `www-data` is the server's username. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When I run your PHP with an input file with a format implied by how you are parsing it, it works as you describe it should.  Quite possibly it's simply a permissions problem, as suggested by BradzTech's answer.

Regardless, what might help troubleshoot is adding `print "$line\n";` and `print_r($fields);` and `print_r($vticket);` to make sure you are reading and parsing what you think you are.

I would ditch the `fixstring` C program for troubleshooting; I think it's just complicating things for you.  Just use PHP to print out the variables you are setting, and troubleshoot from the first point where that output differs from what is expected.

**EDIT** : minimal example showing that the code works ...

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your PHP code.  When I run the below, which is your code with my suggested debugging added and with the HTML trimmed down, using the input line from your comment on your question, I obtain the result you are expecting:

**`cat vmbrr.v2.6.6.vticketQ.log`**

```
vticket: 15 | From: John Doe | To: Jane Doe | Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 16:11:29 +0000 | User: Phil Collins | Program: TruthorDare | Issue: Cannot read text into v ariable | Area: 51 | POC: C. Darwin | Chargeline: R&D | ECD: 02/15/19 | Status: 0%
```

**`cat read-text-from-file.php`**

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("vmbrr.v2.6.6.vticketQ.log", "r");

$line = fgets($handle);
// process the line read.
$fields = explode("|",$line);
print_r($fields);
print "\n";

// Get data from fields
$vticket = explode (":", $fields[0]);
print_r($vticket);
print "\n";

$vTicket=$vticket[1];
$mytest=$vTicket;
print "$mytest\n";

fclose($handle);
?>

<TD width=24><input name="thing1" value="<?php print $mytest;?>"></TD>
```

**`php read-text-from-file.php`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => vticket: 15 
    [1] =>  From: John Doe 
    [2] =>  To: Jane Doe 
    [3] =>  Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 16:11:29 +0000 
    [4] =>  User: Phil Collins 
    [5] =>  Program: TruthorDare 
    [6] =>  Issue: Cannot read text into v ariable 
    [7] =>  Area: 51 
    [8] =>  POC: C. Darwin 
    [9] =>  Chargeline: R&D 
    [10] =>  ECD: 02/15/19 
    [11] =>  Status: 0%

)

Array
(
    [0] => vticket
    [1] =>  15 
)

 15 

<TD width=24><input name="thing1" value=" 15 "></TD>
```

Thus, I believe it's a non-code issue, such as not being able to read the input file, perhaps due to permissions; there are many other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks I verified the permissions are the same as the 20+ other php scripts i have that work properly. I even opened it up with full perms just to make sure.

Comment: @inclineprovo : it's the permissions on the *input file* that matter; can the PHP script read the input file? ...

Comment: yes - it reads the input file fine. I have temporarily opened up the permissions for testing.